# Variable value has not changed in Ajax.reload datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a problem in my code. I can't change the `year` values in my Datatable

This code gets the actual year:

```
var yearDate = new Date();

var year = yearDate.getFullYear();
```

My datatable method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    januaryTable = $('#january').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [],


        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('gastos/ajax_list/')?>" + year+'-01-01' +'/'+ year+'-01-31',
            "type": "POST",

        },

        "columnDefs": [
            { 
                "targets": [ -1 ],
                "orderable": false,
            },
        ],

    });
}
```

This code reloads my datatable

```
function reload_january_table()
{
    januaryTable.ajax.reload(null,false);

}
```

I change the var `year` with a select method and it calls the function reload_january_table(), but for example, when I select the value `2016`, the table doesn't get values from 2016, it keeps the `2017` values.

Can someone help me ? And sorry for my english if it isn't good.

Comment: How is your _select method_ implemented?

Comment: It has changed the var year value, because i use it in a function.

Comment: function Redirect(obj){
var yearO = obj.value;
year = yearO;
reload_january_table();
reload_january_total_invoice();
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `ajax.url` is only being evaluated when the table is initialised, so the first value of your year variable gets “burnt” in to the url.

The solution is to set the new url for DataTables when the value of year changes like so:

```
dataTable.ajax.url('NEW_URL').load();
```

You will find the related part of the DataTables documentation under [`ajax.url()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()).

In your specific case, you could pass in the new value of year as an argument into the `reload_january_table(year)` function call and have that function use that like below.

```
function reload_january_table(year) {
    var newUrl = "<?php echo site_url('gastos/ajax_list/')?>" + year  + '-01-01' + '/' + year + '-01-31';

    januaryTable.ajax.url(newUrl).load();
}
```